# Qual a melhor maneira de trabalhar com os dados do usuário vindos do servidor?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Estou em um projeto de um aplicativo (mobile) de vendas on-line.

Qual a melhor maneira de trabalhar com os dados vindos das tabelas? SQLite, JSON, criando uma classe, Localstorage?

Por exemplo, quando logo, não quero estar toda hora indo no servidor para buscar informações do usuário.

Levando em consideração que eu não quero usar JAVA na aplicação. Utilizo a plataforma IntelXDK e desenvolvo aplicativos multiplataforma. "Localmente" eles são baseados em cima de HTML5, Javascript, Ajax, CSS.
Do lado servidor, eu utilizo PHP para tratar dados e me comunicar com MySQL.

Eu quero *minimizar a comunicação entre PHP e Javascript*.

Comment: Blz utluiz, é apenas uma aplicação para mobile, não um site... Só que, para lidar com dados como por exemplo criar um carrinho de compras, somar multiplus produtos, carregar listas com ajax, gostaria de ter na memoria local (Client-Side), realizar todas as manipulações, e depois inserir no servidor... Até mesmo ao logar, trazer todos os dados do usuário e trabalhar com eles localmente... Tipo o gmail! Agora não entendi quanto a performance: "eu diria que buscar informações do usuário é sua menor preocupação"

Comment: Nesta parte de desempenho, penso que uma vez que, a maioria da população depende muitas vezes de um 3g/4g, quanto menos acessos ao servidor melhor, e também pensando na quantidade de acessos simultâneos com informações praticamente estáticas... Talvez isso não seja um problema então? Quanto a parte de e-commerce, vejo mais como uma boa elaboração de projeto!

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage é o caminho a seguir. Só o OperaMini ainda não o aceita, se precisa suportá-lo vai ter que fazer código especial para ele, até onde eu sei não tem boa solução. Provavelmente terá que usar JSON em *cookies*, o que é limitante e uma péssima ideia.

De qualquer forma não abuse do LocalStorage, ele não foi feito para ser um banco de dados completo. Se se prepare para os dados que espera não estarem lá e ter que recorrer ao servidor.

O custo de pegar dados no servidor costuma ser pequeno, se não for no seu caso talvez esteja abusando. Há vantagens em se pegar os dados do servidor, a principal delas é a segurança.